# how to test routing in angularjs

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, routes, directive, karma-runner

```
app.directive('ngRef', function($location, $timeout){
    linkFn = function(sco,ele,att){
        ele.bind('click', function(){
//            console.log($location);
            $timeout(function(){
                $location.path(att.ngRef);
            }, 0);
        })
    }
    return linkFn;
})
```

here I click on the element and should take me to the ng-ref pointer, which works.

now I write a unit test:

```
describe('routing', function(){
    var mockLocation = null, mockRootScope
    beforeEach(inject(function(){
        module('app')
        inject(function($location, $rootScope){
            mockLocation = $location;
            mockRootScope = $rootScope;
        })
    }))

    it('should route well', function(){
        var elem = angular.element('<button ng-ref="/contact">Click</button>');
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        expect(mockLocation.path).toBe('/home'); //true
        mockCompile(elem)(scope);
        elem[0].click();

        scope.$apply();
        mockTimeout.flush();
        expect(mockLocation.path()).toBe('/contact'); //false
    })
})
```

the expect(mockLocation.path()).toBe('/contact') always shows an error of expected '/home' to be '/contact', how can I change path of $location in this scenario? inside the test? is this a timeout issue?

Comment: This is an old post from the google group, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/F0jFWC4G9hI/FNz3oQu0RhYJ Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Use karma to test the angularjs route. [Here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) is the documentation.

Comment: i'm using karma, but I cant get location.path to work properly.

Comment: what problem you are getting in location.path ?